# How can I access spark web UI using GCP instance?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

I'm using spark on Google Cloud Platform instance(hana express).

I installed spark and run spark shell, then shell is well running but I can't access spark web UI.
I added fire wall rules to instance but still doesn't work.
I added screen shot.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please include code and output as text in your question, not as a picture. In it's present form, it is unreadable on many devices and essentially invisible to assistive technologies.

Comment: IT IS INTERNAL DNS.

Comment: Thank you for comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the console messages:

```
...
Spark context Web UI available at http://sap-hanaexpress-serverinclapps-1-vm.c.hana.271411.internal:4040
...
```

**You're not able to reach Web UI running at** `http://sap-hanaexpress-serverinclapps-1-vm.c.hana.271411.internal:4040` from your remote PC. As it was mentioned by *@Lamanus* this record is for internal usage only. Have a look at the documentation [Internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns):

> Virtual Private Cloud networks on Google Cloud have an **internal DNS
>   service that lets instances in the same network access each other by
>   using internal DNS names**. Internal A records for virtual machine (VM)
>   instances are created in a DNS zone for `.internal`. PTR records for VM
>   instances are created in corresponding reverse zones. As you manage
>   your instances, Google Cloud automatically creates, updates, and
>   removes these DNS records.

and

> The internal DNS name of a VM instance only resolves to its primary
>   internal IP address. **Internal DNS names cannot be used to connect to
>   the external IP addresses of an instance**.

**To solve this issue** follow steps below:

1. add the `SPARK_LOCAL_IP="<IP address>"` to your configuration file as it suggested in console messages where `IP address` is local IP of your VM
2. [set network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) to your VM
3. [create firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to enable incoming connections to your VM at port 4040
4. check your firewall by running `nmap -Pn EXTENAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM` from your pc
5. check Web UI via browser `http://EXTENAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM:4040`